# Problem with ASP.NET Membership application

Tags: iis, asp.net-membership

I have two same application published in IIS in under different web sites and ports:

http://myapp:82

http://myapp:83

I have the same membership connections strings in each application. When i get list of users from db I see users which created in another web site. As I know IIS automaticaly must categorize via ID membership information. But I haven't isolation between my apps.

**I don't want to see membership data from another application.**

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use the applicationName property when defining the membersip settings in web.config.

Here is the [applicationName article on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.applicationname.aspx)

Comment: When I show ApplictionName for example "someApp "in db ApplicationName is "/". Why application name not change

Comment: Hi @Polaris, I'm guessing that "/" is there because it's what the users were set to use originally. You may find this link useful, it's not the same problem as your facing, but gives you some background information on applicationName: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/22/Always-set-the-_2200_applicationName_2200_-property-when-configuring-ASP.NET-2.0-Membership-and-other-Providers.aspx

Comment: I've already read this article .I configure my config and create new app in iis and then create user. Nothing changed. ApplicationName is "/" yet